# How to provide Calendar and Mail Services to asp.net mvc web site users

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In our asp.net mvc based web site, we want to allow users to manage their calendar and emails.
We don't want to develop these services on our own as there are too complex and time consuming.

Are there any open source projects that we can adopt? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendar Here: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asp-net-mvc-calendar.aspx)

As for email I am not aware of anything currently, but it's not the type of thing people will make without cause, or at least not this early on. The email management should be a lot simpler to implement than the calendar though, so I say take the time to make one, simply because you have got the cause.